# Passport authentication having error but not able to find the error

Tags: authentication, postman, passport.js

```js
//index.js

const express = require('express'),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
  uuid = require('uuid'),
  morgan = require('morgan'),
  fs = require('fs'),
  path = require('path');

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Models = require('./models.js');

const Movies = Models.Movie;
const Users = Models.User;

// //allows Mongoose connect to database to perform CRUD
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/cfDB', {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
});

const app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
let auth = require('./auth')(app); //import auth.js and ensure Express available in auth file.
const passport = require('passport');
require('./passport');

//create write stream
const accessLogStream = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, 'log.txt'), {
  flags: 'a'
});

//set up logger
app.use(morgan('combined', {
  stream: accessLogStream
}));


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Welcome to myFlix!');
});

app.get('/documentation', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('public/documentation.html', {
    root: __dirname
  });
});


//READ list of movies
app.get('/movies', passport.authenticate('jwt', {
  session: false
}), (req, res) => {
  Movies.find()
    .then((movies) => {
      res.status(200).json(movies);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send('Error: ' + err)
    });
});

//READ - list of users
app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
  Users.find()
    .then((users) => {
      res.status(200).json(users);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send('Error: ' + err)
    });
});


//READ - find movie by title
app.get('/movies/:Title', (req, res) => {
  Movies.findOne({
      Title: req.params.Title
    })
    .then((movie) => {
      res.json(movie);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send('Error: ' + err);
    });
});

//READ - return genre data by name
app.get('/movies/genre/:genreName', (req, res) => {
  Movies.findOne({
      'Genre.Name': req.params.genreName
    })
    .then((movie) => {
      res.json(movie.Genre);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send('Error: ' + err);
    });
});

//READ - return director data by name
app.get('/movies/director/:directorName', (req, res) => {
  Movies.findOne({
      'Director.Name': req.params.directorName
    })
    .then((movie) => {
      res.json(movie.Director);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send('Error: ' + err);
    });
});


// CREATE - new user register
app.post('/users', (req, res) => {
  Users.findOne({
      Username: req.body.Username
    })
    .then((user) => {
      if (user) {
        return res.status(400).send(req.body.Username + ' already exists');
      } else {
        Users.create({
            Username: req.body.Username,
            Password: req.body.Password,
            Email: req.body.Email,
            Birthday: req.body.Birthday
          })
          .then((user) => {
            res.status(200).json(user)
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
            res.status(500).send('Error: ' + error);
          });
      }
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
      res.status(500).send('Error: ' + error);
    });
});

// UPDATE - user update username
app.put('/users/:Username', async function(req, res) {
  let updatedUser;
  try {
    updatedUser = await Users.findOneAndUpdate({
      Username: req.params.Username
    }, {
      $set: {
        Username: req.body.Username,
        Password: req.body.Password,
        Email: req.body.Email,
        Birthday: req.body.Birthday
      }
    }, {
      new: true
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return res.status(500).send('Error: ' + err);
  }
  return res.json(updatedUser);
})

// CREATE - user add movie to favourites
app.put('/users/:Username/movies/:MovieID', async function(req, res) {
  let updatedUser;
  try {
    updatedUser = await Users.findOneAndUpdate({
      Username: req.params.Username
    }, {
      $push: {
        Favorite: req.params.MovieID
      }
    }, {
      new: true
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return res.status(500).send('Error: ' + err);
  }
  return res.json(req.params.MovieID + 'has been added to ' + req.params.Username + ' list of favorite movies');
})

// DELETE - users remove movie from favourites
app.delete('/users/:Username/movies/:MovieID', async function(req, res) {
  let updatedUser;
  try {
    updatedUser = await Users.findOneAndUpdate({
      Username: req.params.Username
    }, {
      $pull: {
        Favorite: req.params.MovieID
      }
    }, {
      new: true
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return res.status(500).send('Error: ' + err);
  }
  return res.json(req.params.MovieID + 'has been removed from ' + req.params.Username + ' list of favorite movies');
})

// DELETE - user deregister
app.delete('/users/:Username', (req, res) => {
  Users.findOneAndRemove({
      Username: req.params.Username
    })
    .then((user) => {
      if (!user) {
        res.status(400).send(req.params.Username + ' was not found');
      } else {
        res.status(200).send(req.params.Username + ' was deleted');
      }
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send('Error: ' + err);
    });
});

// //error handling 
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.error(err.stack);
  res.status(500).send('Something broke!');
})

//listen req
app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log('myFlix is running on port 8080');
});
```

I am working on a movie API that could provide information on movies details.

Currently, learning full stack as a student.

I am learning authentication and authorisation using Passport and defined the strategies.

Will attach my index.js, auth.js and passport.js

I tested on Postman when reading data on all movies - it indicates unauthorised which is correct.

After creating a user, and trying to read data on all movies and indicated username and password in Params:
the message is something is not right.

I am not too sure where is wrong - i couldn't figure it out.

Please let me know what information you need besides my 3 file code.. I have also attached photo of MongoDB with the user created.

```js
//passport.js

const passport = require('passport'),
  LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy,
  Models = require('./models.js'),
  passportJWT = require('passport-jwt');

let Users = Models.User,
  JWTStrategy = passportJWT.Strategy,
  ExtractJWT = passportJWT.ExtractJwt;

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'Username',
    passwordField: 'Password'
  },
  (username, password, callback) => {
    console.log(username + ' ' + password);
    Users.findOne({
      Username: username
    }, (error, user) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return callback(error);
      }

      if (!user) {
        console.log('incorrect username');
        return callback(null, false, {
          message: "Incorrect username or password."
        });
      }

      console.log('finished');
      return callback(null, user);
    });
  }));

passport.use(new JWTStrategy({
  jwtFromRequest: ExtractJWT.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
  secretOrKey: 'your_jwt_secret'
}, (jwtPayload, callback) => {
  return Users.findById(jwtPayload._id)
    .then((user) => {
      return callback(null, user);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      return callback(error)
    });
}));
```

```js
//auth.js

//same key used in JWTStrategy
const jwtSecret = 'your_jwt_secret';

const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'),
  passport = require('passport');

//local passport file
require('./passport');

let generateJWTToken = (user) => {
  return jwt.sign(user, jwtSecret, {
    subject: user.Username, //username encoding in JWT
    expiresIn: '7d', //token will expire in 7 days
    algorithm: 'HS256' //algorithn used to "sign" or encode values of JWT
  });
}

//POST login
module.exports = (router) => {
  router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    passport.authenticate('local', {
      session: false
    }, (error, user, info) => {
      if (error || !user) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          message: 'Something is not right',
          user: user
        });
      }
      req.login(user, {
        session: false
      }, (error) => {
        if (error) {
          res.send(error);
        }
        let token = generateJWTToken(user.toJSON());
        return res.json({
          user,
          token
        }); //this returns the token
      });
    })(req, res);
  })
}
```

[error on postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1avS.png)

There should be JWT token assigned to the user when I POST with the username and password.

Then, be able to read data on the movies.

but i am getting something is not right message.